# Using a template the row height of a grid in the template doesn't initially set correctly?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have this XAML, it uses a custom template three times and then after that a ViewCell, Grid etc all hard coded:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <TableView Intent="Settings" HasUnevenRows="false" RowHeight="50" x:Name="atiSection">
        <TableView.Root>
            <TableSection Title="Set the amount of time that the answer will remain visible on the Play screen">
                <template:SwitchViewCellTemplate Text="{Binding [0].Name}" 
                    IsVisible="{Binding [0].IsSelected}" 
                    SelectAction="Handle_SelectAction" />
                <template:SwitchViewCellTemplate Text="{Binding [1].Name}" 
                    IsVisible="{Binding [1].IsSelected}" 
                    SelectAction="Handle_SelectAction" />
                <template:SwitchViewCellTemplate Text="{Binding [2].Name}" 
                    IsVisible="{Binding [2].IsSelected}" 
                    SelectAction="Handle_SelectAction" />
                <ViewCell Tapped="selectValue" >
                    <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20,0" >
                        <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding [3].Name}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
                        <local:StyledLabel IsVisible="{Binding [3].IsSelected}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="✓" />
                    </Grid>
                </ViewCell>
```

To make things cleaner I created a template which in this example is used three times:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ViewCell xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
          xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Japanese;assembly=Japanese"
          x:Class="Japanese.SwitchViewCellTemplate"
          x:Name="this" >
   <Grid VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand" Padding="20,0" >
      <local:StyledLabel Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" />
      <local:StyledLabel IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Source={x:Reference this}}" TextColor="Gray" HorizontalOptions="End" Text="✓" />
   </Grid>
</ViewCell>
```

Here's the back end CS code initialize:

```
    SSVViewModel[] AnswerTimeInterval = new[] {
            new SSVViewModel{  Id = 0, Name = ATI.Two.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
            new SSVViewModel{  Id = 1, Name = ATI.Three.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
            new SSVViewModel{  Id = 2, Name = ATI.Five.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
            new SSVViewModel{  Id = 3, Name = ATI.Ten.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
            new SSVViewModel{  Id = 4, Name = ATI.Fifteen.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
            new SSVViewModel{  Id = 5, Name = ATI.Thirty.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
            new SSVViewModel{  Id = 6, Name = ATI.Sixty.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
            new SSVViewModel{  Id = 7, Name = ATI.ThreeHundred.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
            new SSVViewModel{  Id = 8, Name = ATI.SixHundred.Text(), IsSelected = false} ,
        };
    public ATIPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        atiSection.BindingContext = AnswerTimeInterval;
    }
```

When the page first appears it looks like this:

[image]

After I click on the first of the three cells it changes to this:

[image]

Does anyone have any ideas why the text in the lines might initially show with almost no height and then why it would get bigger when I click on the view cell?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **AndExpand** `LayoutOptions` [are only for use by a `StackLayout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/layouts/layout-options), although I'm not sure if that is the root cause of the issue. Changing the template grid to the following seems to fix the issue:

```xaml
   <Grid Padding="20,0">
      <Label Text="{Binding Text, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
             VerticalTextAlignment="Center"/>
      <Label HorizontalOptions="End" 
             IsVisible="{Binding IsVisible, Source={x:Reference this}}" 
             Text="✓"
             TextColor="Gray"
             VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />
   </Grid>
```

[Performance tips](https://kent-boogaart.com/blog/jason-smith's-xamarin-forms-performance-tips) from Jason Smith (Xamarin.Forms creator) mention the following as well:

> PREFER the `VerticalTextAlignment` and `HorizontalTextAlignment`
>   properties of `Label` over `VerticalOptions` and `HorizontalOptions`.